JS scroll listener for animation causing page jump during mobile scroll
I have written some custom code for an 'animation'.  The animation counts for 0 to a certain number as specified in the function.  This works fine on desktop but on my android phone it is causing the page to jump back up a little bit when you scroll down to this section of the page.  You also cannot see the animation.  It seems like it:

Triggers the animation
Jumps back up the back the page a little as the animation runs
User scrolls down again and it shows the updated numbers after the count up animation is done

This is the page I have the problem on: https://quedamoslanguages.com/ so you can see the bug here.
The section to look at is the 'YEARS EXPERIENCE', 'STUDENTS' etc. It is 2/3 down the page.
This is the custom function
import { runOnScroll, throttle } from './common.js';

function doCountAnimation(element, targetNumber, duration = 1000) {
    if (!element) {
        console.error(`Element with selector '${elementSelector}' not found.`);
        return;
    }
    const startTime = performance.now();
    function updateCount(currentTime) {
        const elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
        const progress = Math.min(elapsedTime / duration, 1);
        const currentNumber = Math.floor(progress * targetNumber);
        element.textContent = currentNumber;
        if (progress < 1) {
            requestAnimationFrame(updateCount); // requestAnimationFrame() is build in browser function
        }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(updateCount);
}


function triggerCountAnimation(element){
    doCountAnimation(element.querySelector('div.wp-block-group:nth-child(1) p:nth-child(1)'), 31);
    doCountAnimation(element.querySelector('div.wp-block-group:nth-child(2) p:nth-child(1)'), 7);
    doCountAnimation(element.querySelector('div.wp-block-group:nth-child(3) p:nth-child(1)'), 14);
    doCountAnimation(element.querySelector('.wp-block-group:nth-child(4) p:nth-child(1)'), 1000);
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', throttledScrollHandler);
}

const throttledScrollHandler = throttle(() => runOnScroll('.big-numbers-container-home .wp-block-group', triggerCountAnimation), 300);

// Throttling the function with an anonymous wrapper to pass the selector
window.addEventListener('scroll', throttledScrollHandler, { passive: true });



And these are the 2 functions which I am importing
export const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
    // Set up the throttlerconst throttle = (fn, delay) => {
    let time = Date.now();
    return () => {
        if ((time + delay - Date.now()) <= 0) {
            fn();
            time = Date.now();
        }
    };
}

export function runOnScroll(selector, animationFn) {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (element) {
        if(isInViewport(element)){
            animationFn(element)
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Element not found for selector:', selector);
    }
}

As you can see I have throttled the function so that the scroll function does not run all the time in order to improve performance.
I did try taking the throttle function out so did this -
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => runOnScroll('.big-numbers-container-home .wp-block-group', triggerCountAnimation), { passive: true });
But was still seeing the same issue.  Of course I just want the page to scroll from top to bottom without jumping around anywhere in the process.
Any ideas would be much appreciated !

I don't see anything jumping out at me since you excluded the throttle function as the problem. Are there any console logs when you run on phone? It's so annoying when things are bugged only on phone and not even on the phone simulator (built into dev tools). My suggestion is putting print commands in your functions, and see how many times/when they run, and see if it's behaving as you intended. I also want to point out there's a chance the problem is part of some other code.

It is only on android too, works fine on apple phones !  Thanks for sanity checking the code :) Have got another plugin which does some animation functions so I think it must be that which is causing the issue possibly combined with the some caching performance plugin which delays JS execution..!
